# what should I do? I got an error which is " element name=password not found - selenium "

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium IDE with firefox for recording test cases and login and logout from gmail.when I stop recording the test cases and then start the test case for login then I get the error:

> "element name=password not found"

what should I do?
sorry I am not good at explaining.can anyone help me?

Comment: how are you recording the script ? is it own a fresh brwoser or browser that asks only for password but email is already available

Comment: I am using a fresh browser.